# Failed to execute goal Failed to execute goal on project : Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 17

Tags: java, linux, maven, heroku

i have this problem when i'm tring to build my project on Heroku.

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:compile (default-compile) on project ecommerce: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 17 ->
```

I checked java version and maven by mvn -v

```
Apache Maven 3.6.3
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 17.0.5, vendor: Private Build, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "5.15.0-52-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

In my pom.xml i have also java version 17

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.wiktor</groupId>
    <artifactId>ecommerce</artifactId>
    <version>0.98.4</version>
    <name>ecommerce</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Can someone help me to solve this problem? when im trying to run maven clear install this problem happening again, also with maven test.
.

Comment: Two things. First: `invalid target release: 17 ` this tells you that you are not really using JDK17+ so my question: Do you use the same user for execution where you got that failure and for `mvn --version` ? Apart of that it looks like you are not really using Maven 3.6.3 because that version is a repackaged version of Maven (assumption: You are on Ubuntu?) Furthermore you are using a very old version because current version is 3.8.6....

Comment: 1. Yes, im using SDKs openjdk17 in project structure menu. Yes I'm on the same User.
i can't initialize maven install  because, i got this error `The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (/home/wiktor). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. ->`
2. Yes, im on Linux Ubuntu

Comment: You are not executing via command line? From IDE? The output posted says you are not in the correct directory... you have to change the location into the directory where the pom file is located.

Comment: Ok, thank you now it works xD. But still i have no clue why i have a problem with invalid target release. I'm using java 17 from the begining. It is possible that i have a wrong path or something ?

Comment: You might configured the JDK in your IDE which might be different one than on the command line... ?

Comment: I see the problem in my IDE i have a old maven version i think it is to old because i need to have 3.8.1+. Do you know how can i update it in my project? In command line i have 3.8.6 already, but in IDE i have 3.6.3. In my IDE i have Java version 17.0.5 so its ok but maven is too old.